# Android in-app purchase fails in my adapter

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a list which has a `buy` button and on click of this button I would like to make an in-app purchase.

I have created an interface and also a function in my fragment but I am getting following error.

```
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.chinese.flashcard.ShopActivity cannot be cast to com.chinese.flashcard.TestAdapter$IABHelperProvider
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at com.chinese.flashcard.TestAdapter.getView(TestAdapter.java:82)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
05-11 11:02:03.224: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
```

Comment: Post your adapter class code. And what is in the line number  82 in your adapter class?

Comment: 82 line mHelper = ((IABHelperProvider) context).getHelper();

Comment: public interface IABHelperProvider {
  public IabHelper getHelper();
 }
 
 
 public TestAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
  super(context, resource);
  this.context = context;
 }

 
 

 public TestAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Row> rowItem) {

  super(context, resourceId, rowItem);
  this.context = context;
 }

 private class ViewHolder {

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  TextView categaery, purchase_point, buy;

 }

Comment: holder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    /*
     * TODO: for security, generate your payload here for
     * verification. See the comments on verifyDeveloperPayload()
     * for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use an empty
     * string, but on a production app you should carefully generate
     * this.
     */
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(origin, SKU_INAPPITEM, 10000,
      mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
   }

  });

Comment: Your code posted as comments is unreadable due to lack of formatting. Edit your original question, posting the code in code blocks. If people can read your code, they can probably suggest solutions.